# Apache2 on Ubuntu gives Py_Initialize ImportError: No module named encodings

Tags: python, django, apache2, wsgi

I'm working on Ubuntu with Apache2, Python 3.6.1. I followed the directions here to set it up with Django and mod_wsgi: [How To Serve Django Applications with Apache and mod_wsgi on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-14-04)

I've looked at a lot of similar questions and still can't get it to work. The Apache error log spews the "ImportError: No module named 'encodings' almost constantly.

Here are the relevant settings in my Apache2 files:

In 000-default.conf:

```
    WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-home=/home/user/myproject/myprojectenv/ python-path=/home/user/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/python
    WSGIProcessGroup myproject
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/myproject/myprojectenv/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py
```

In apache2.conf:

```
    WSGIPythonPath /home/user/myproject/myprojectenv
```

Note that, when I check sys.prefix it equals what I have in the WSGIPythonPath above.

Yes, I've activated the virtual environment.
For my environment variables, I have:

```
    PATH = /home/user/myproject/myprojectenv/bin:$PATH
    PYTHONPATH = /home/user/myproject/myprojectenv/bin:$PYTHONPATH
    PYTHONHOME = not set
```

I've tried various combinations of the environment variables being set and not being set. None that I've tried have worked.

When I followed the steps from the link above, I'm not sure that a new mod_wsgi was built that is for Python 3.6.1. I had tried (on another copy of my VM) to explicitly build a Python shared library and to build mod_wsgi with that. It failed miserably. I hesitate to go that route again unless I'm sure that's what I need to do.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Directories on the python path should contain modules that python can load. It doesn't make sense to have a `bin` directory of binaries in the Python patch. The tutorial you linked to shows to use `WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-path=/home/user/myproject python-home=/home/user/myproject/myprojectenv` - set `python-path` to the project and `python-home` for the virtual env.

Comment: You don't have to compile mod_wsgi if you install `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3` and use the default Python 3 for your version of Ubuntu (you haven't said which version you are using)

Comment: Originally, we were using a Python 3.6.1 that we installed ourselves, but I switched to the virtual environment and am using the python 3.6.1 installed there. I had the python-path set like the tutorial originally but have tried a lot of things to get it to work. I will switch back to that and try again. Thanks @Alasdair

Comment: @Alasdair - I changed the file and restart apache but I get the same error.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04. That was how I installed wsgi, so that should be okay. It may be that we are using Python 3.6.1 and not 3.4, which seems to be the latest installed by default.

Comment: As I said, you can use `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3` if you use the default Python 3 for that version of Ubuntu. For Ubuntu 14.04 that means Python 3.4. If you are using Python 3.6 + Ubuntu 14.04 then you'll have to compile mod_wsgi.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that again. Since I screwed it up the first time, suggestions would be appreciated. It doesn't look like there is a shared library for Python so I need to do that first.

Comment: @Alasdair I did need to build python and mod_wsgi. That then gave me an error "libpython3.6m.so.1.0 cannot open shared object file". That is resolved by adding the path to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH *and* running ldconfig. That last piece is what I had missed before. If you want to summarize your comments in an answer, I'll give it an upvote.

Comment: Glad you got it working. It would probably be better for you to answer your own question, since you know the changes that were required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did get passed this error. As @Alasdair pointed out, I did need to build Python with a shared library and then build mod_wsgi with that version of Python. I followed the directions here: [Compiling mod_wsgi for a custom Python Build](http://www.cysec.org/blog/2011/06/10/compiling-mod_wsgi-for-a-custom-python-build/index.html)

The only difference is that I needed to add 'sudo' before 'make install' so the permissions were good for putting the module in the /usr/bin/apache2/modules directory.

I also needed to be sure LD_LIBRARY_PATH recognized the python library (I received a "error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.6m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" error). That error was cleaned up by using 'ldconfig'.

I'm still having an Apache issue, which I will write up separately, but this got me passed the 'encodings' problem.